# Insert constraint issue

Tags: informix

Using IBM Informix database.
If I specify order_no manually, the statement works but if I try to increment it within the query, it fails.

Table structure

```
patkey serial
notetype char(4)
order_no int
```

The constraint is patkey, notetype and order_no

I can manually insert running the following and increment the order_no

```
insert into patnotes (patkey, notetype, order_no) values (5000, 'GEN', 3)
```

I wanted to increment it within the insert statement but I get a duplicate violation and don't understand how.

Here is the insert statement that I'm trying to use to increment the order_no.

```
INSERT INTO patnotes (patkey, notetype, order_no)
SELECT FIRST 1 
    p.personkey, 
    'GEN' as notetype, 
    CASE WHEN n.order_no is null then 1 else (n.order_no + 1) end as order_no
FROM 
    person p 
LEFT JOIN 
    patnotes n 
    ON p.personkey = n.patkey 
    AND n.notetype = 'GEN'
WHERE 
    p.patid = '5000'
ORDER BY 
    n.order_no DESC
```

Checking the table the following entries exist

```
5000, GEN, 1
5000, GEN, 2
```

The next order should be 3.

Running the select portion of the above insert statement gives:

```
5000, GEN, 3
```

This is correct but fails the constraint. If I enter these manually in the first insert statement, there is no issue.

Now the next odd issue is if I clear out these entries so the first entry is order_no 1.

This will add entries for order_no 1 and 2 but then fails for 3+ but again if I specify this manually in just an insert statement, no issues.

I'm not seeing what I'm missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using a recent 12.10 Informix version, the online [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0878.htm#ids_sqs_0878) states:

> As indicated in the INSERT statement syntax diagram, not all clauses
>   and options of the SELECT statement are available for you to use in a
>   query within an INSERT statement. The following SELECT clauses and
>   options are not supported in an INSERT statement:
>
> - FIRST and LIMIT
> - INTO TEMP, INTO RAW, and INTO STANDARD result table options
> - UNION, UNION ALL, INTERSECT, MINUS, and EXCEPT set operators.

So `FIRST` is not supported in `SELECT` statements used in an `INSERT` context. But using `FIRST` in the query does not give any syntax error, so maybe something else is going on.

```
-- The setup
CREATE TABLE patnotes
(
     patkey    SERIAL
    , notetype CHAR(4)
    , order_no INTEGER
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX patnotes_udx1 ON patnotes(patkey, notetype, order_no);

INSERT INTO patnotes VALUES (5000, 'GEN', 1);
INSERT INTO patnotes VALUES (5000, 'GEN', 2);

CREATE TABLE person
(
      personkey INTEGER
    , patid     CHAR(4)
);

INSERT INTO person VALUES (4999, '4999');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (5000, '5000');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (5001, '5001');

-- The insert query
INSERT INTO patnotes (patkey, notetype, order_no)
SELECT FIRST 1 
    p.personkey
    , 'GEN' AS notetype
    , CASE 
        WHEN n.order_no IS NULL THEN 1 
        ELSE (n.order_no + 1) 
      END AS order_no
FROM 
    person p 
LEFT JOIN 
    patnotes n 
    ON p.personkey = n.patkey 
    AND n.notetype = 'GEN'
WHERE 
    p.patid = '5000'
ORDER BY 
    n.order_no DESC;
```

When we run the above `INSERT` we get:

```
239: Could not insert new row - duplicate value in a UNIQUE INDEX column (Unique Index:patnotes_udx1).
100: ISAM error:  duplicate value for a record with unique key.
```

If we remove the `UNIQUE` constraint and run the `INSERT` multiple times we keep getting the same value for column `order_no` .

```
-- remove the UNIQUE
DROP INDEX patnotes_udx1;

-- Run the insert multiple times and we get
SELECT * FROM patnotes;
patkey notetype    order_no

  5000 GEN                1
  5000 GEN                2
  5000 GEN                2
  5000 GEN                2
  5000 GEN                2
  5000 GEN                2
  5000 GEN                2
  5000 GEN                2
  5000 GEN                2
  5000 GEN                2
```

It keeps inserting the same calculated `order_no` . Seems like a bug. You should open a defect with Informix support.

As a workaround you can use `MAX` to calculate `order_no`:

```
INSERT INTO patnotes (patkey, notetype, order_no)      
SELECT
    p.personkey
    , 'GEN' AS notetype
    , (MAX(NVL(n.order_no,0)) + 1) AS order_no
FROM
    person p
LEFT JOIN
    patnotes n
    ON p.personkey = n.patkey
    AND n.notetype = 'GEN'
WHERE
    p.patid = '5000'
GROUP BY
    p.personkey, notetype
;
```

Please do note that this approach will fail miserably if you have multiple sessions trying to insert new values concurrently. You should use `SERIAL` or create a `SEQUENCE` to generate the `order_no` values.